# Swift 3 / Xcode 9. MTLBuffer 'didModifyRange' is unavailable

Tags: xcode, metal, mtlbuffer

I'm trying to tell a MTLBuffer that the range has changed but the compiler won't let me do that:

```
vertexBuffer?.didModifyRange(NSMakeRange(0,MemoryLayout<MetalVertex>.stride*nbVerts))
```

it just says: 'didModifyRange' is unavailable
why is that?

thanks

Answer (score 1):

In Swift, [`didModifyRange`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/metal/mtlbuffer/2928174-didmodifyrange) takes a `Range<Int>`, not an `NSRange`. So instead of using `NSMakeRange`, you can construct one using the `..<` operator.

```
vertexBuffer?.didModifyRange(0 ..< MemoryLayout<MetalVertex>.stride * nbVerts)
```

Comment: thanks for the Answer Rick, I've tried your suggestion but I get this error: Cannot convert value of type 'CountableRange<Int>' to expected argument type 'NSRange' (aka '_NSRange').

Answer (score 0):

Are you targeting iOS?  Per the [Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/metal/mtlbuffer/1516121-didmodifyrange), `didModifyRange` is only supported on macOS and Catalyst.  It also only applies to buffers created with `MTLStorageModeManaged`, which has the same constraints.

If you're targeting multiple platforms, you will need to make both conditional, see:

[Swift availability check for macCatalyst](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69434107/swift-availability-check-for-maccatalyst-ios-failing)