# Swift availability check for macCatalyst / iOS failing

Tags: ios, swift, mac-catalyst, availability

I have added an `iOS 15+/macCatalyst 15.0+` function to my app and now it is crashing when run on an M1 iMac through `Mac Catalyst (Designed for iPad)`.

I have an availability check around my function however when run on my Mac (macOS 11.6), the code within the availability check still runs, and crashes.

```
if #available(iOS 15.0, macCatalyst 15.0, *) {
    dataSource.applySnapshotUsingReloadData(fullSnapshot, completion: nil)
} else {
    dataSource.apply(fullSnapshot, animatingDifferences: false)
}
```

I understand the `Designed for iPad` mac catalyst runs as iOS, and I can confirm it is running as `iOS 14.7` using `print(UIDevice.current.systemVersion)` so why is it running code that is set to run on `iOS 15+` only?

Am I doing my macCatalyst check right?

Comment: Maybe try `#if targetEnvironment(macCatalyst)` for Mac catalyst detection

Comment: Code inside that check doesn't run!

Comment: It turns out, the `macCatalyst` check won't work because it's running as an `iOS` app and not full catalyst. However that doesn't explain why the `iOS 15` check doesn't work.

Comment: The environment check works fine when running on macOS 11.4.

Comment: I am running an `iOS` app on an `M1` mac which apparently is different to running a full `macCatalyst` app. The app runs as if it's `iOS` so the `targetEnvironment` fails. But i've posted below the answer I got from Apple.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It turns out this is a known issue and actually mentioned in the Xcode 13 release notes.

> Availability checks in iPhone and iPad apps on a Mac with Apple
> silicon always return true. This causes iOS apps running in macOS 11
> Big Sur to see iOS 15 APIs as available, resulting in crashes. This
> only affects apps available in the Mac App Store built with the “My
> Mac (Designed for iPhone)” or “My Mac (Designed for iPad)” run
> destination. It doesn’t affect Mac Catalyst apps. (83378814)

> Workaround: Use the following code to check for iOS 15 availability:

```
if #available(iOS 15, *), ProcessInfo.processInfo.operatingSystemVersion.majorVersion >= 15 {
```

Answer (score 6):

I need to check for this but I need to add functionality *if* running as an iOS app on the Mac and this seems to do the trick:

```
if ProcessInfo.processInfo.isiOSAppOnMac {
    // blah blah yada yada etc etc
}
```

There is also an `isMacCatalystApp` value as well.

Comment: how would you use this in a property definition where you need the # ... #endif format